# Cannot update wpf image source

Tags: c#, wpf, image

In my WPF app,i have an `Image` control.On form load,i set it's source to a GIF image as follows :

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage;
image.BeginInit();
image.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/myApp;component/icons/LoadingAnim.gif");
image.EndInit();
WPFAnimatedGif.ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(myimg, image);
```

This works fine however,when the image control's source is already set to the GIF image,i cannot update/change the source.I am using the below code :

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage;
image.BeginInit();
image.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/myApp;component/icons/pc.png");
image.EndInit();
myImg.Source = image;
```

Even this code works but only when the source has not been set before..I don't understand why this is happening..Can someone explain this ?

One thing that i should add, the 2nd code is executed on `BackgriundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` event...Don't if it has to do anything with it ?

Comment: Are there any errors in the output window, when you run your code?

Comment: No....i set breakpoints and there are no null reference exception as well..as i said, both code works but onl for once..if the image source is set once,it can't be changed...dunno why :(

Comment: *"Even this code works but only when the source has not been set before.."* really means it only works when `myImg.Source` was not set, i.e. was `null` before? Sounds odd.

Comment: Do you have to stop the animated gif?

Comment: I just want to change the source of the image control, if that requires to stop the animation so be it... any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: So `loadingInbox` and `myImg` are the same Image element? Anyway, a WPF animation has a default [FillBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) of HoldEnd, which prevents that you can set a dependency property value as long as the animation is there. This may also be true for the ImageBehavior animation. Is there some Stop method in ImageBehavior?

Comment: let me check for the stop method and i'm sorry, myyimg is the image name, i mistakenly typed in loadingInbox :)\

Comment: Try `WPFAnimatedGif.ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(myImg, null)` before setting `myImg.Source`.

Comment: lemme try :)...

Comment: It worked :) Thank u so much :)